# Desktop class doesn't work in NetBeans- java with maven

Tags: maven, file, netbeans, desktop

i'm developing my own program to serach through files (like FileChooser). I have to have option 'open file'. I tried to do it this way:

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\win10\\note.txt");
desktop.open(myFile);
```

In normal javaapplication- it works with import java.awt.Desktop, but it doesn't work in java with maven. DO you have any idead what to do? I attach error information:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to import Desktop class in my NetBeans IDE. What Java version are you using?

For Java 11, I was able to solve it by adding the following modules:

```
requires java.desktop;
```

Comment: well simple clean-build worked as fair as i remember